# Integral of a complicated rational function

Tags: integration

I have a tough integral that I would like your advice on.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be real, $i>0$ an integer, and $\gamma = \gamma(\varepsilon)$ some (known) complicated function of $\varepsilon$.  Essentially,  I need to compute the following integral:

$$\int_{a(\varepsilon)}^{b(\varepsilon)}\frac{x^i}{(1+x^2)^2 \big((x+\gamma)^2+(1-\gamma^2) \big)^{i-1}}\, dx$$

for some equally complicated (and also known) bounding functions $a,b$.

My gut reaction is to compute a brute force partial fraction decomposition and work term-by-term, but this quickly becomes messy.  Is there something "smart" I can do instead?  I suspect there may be a way to handle it more elegantly with residue techniques, but I am not fluent enough to know how, and I couldn't find a similar example in my go-to complex analysis texts.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Also suppose none of the poles lie between $a$ and $b$; that should be reasonable based on my problem.

Comment: I don't expect there would be a particular nice general form. If we denote the integrand by $f_i(x)$, then we have $f_{i + 1}(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 2 \gamma x + 1} f_i(x)$, which suggests trying to set up a recursion relation in $i$ and relating the partial fractions decompositions of $f_i, f_{i + 1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I appreciate it.  I will try this.